# XML produced by web service call does not correspond to the service classes

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I am having a problem with my web service calls in WCF. The XML produced by the service call does not correspond to the classes defined in the Reference.cs generated by Visual Studio. The service references are up to date.

Here are the relevant parts of Reference.cs. Attributes omitted for clarity:

```
public partial class charterBooking : basePublicType {
    private additionalCost[] additionalCostsField;
    //.. lots of other properties
}

public partial class additionalCost : basePublicType {

    private long additionalCostItemIDField;

    private bool additionalCostItemIDFieldSpecified;

    private short categoryField;

    private bool categoryFieldSpecified;

    private short chargeToField;

    //.. lots of other properties
}
```

The XML produced by this call:

```
response = proxy.saveCharterDetails(saveCharterDetails);
```

looks like this (as grabbed by Fiddler):

```
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <saveCharterDetails xmlns="http://bcs.aircharter.co.uk/acs">
         <charterEnquiry xmlns="">
            <brokerCode>EX</brokerCode>
            <charterBooking>
               <additionalCosts>
                  <description>3</description>
                  <supplierName>2</supplierName>
               </additionalCosts>
               <aircraftRegistration/>
               <balanceAmount>205</balanceAmount>
               <!-- ...lots and lots of other xml -->
            </charterBooking>
         </charterEnquiry>
      </saveCharterDetails>
   </s:Body>
```

Here is an extract of the WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="additionalCost">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:basePublicType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="additionalCostAudits" nillable="true" type="tns:additionalCostAudit"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="additionalCostItemID" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="category" type="xs:short"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chargeTo" type="xs:short"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chargeToDetails" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="charterEnquiryID" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dateAdded" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="invoiceCurrency" type="xs:short"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="isDeleted" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="isInvoiceSeparately" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="purchaseCurrency" type="xs:short"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="purchasePrice" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sellCurrency" type="xs:short"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sellPrice" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="supplierName" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, the additionalCost in the XML does not look anything like the additionalCost in the C# entities. It should be an array for one thing!

What am I missing?

M

Comment: Most probably your service reference and wsdl are not sync. Try updating service reference.

Comment: I have done. See above.

Comment: Well then it may be case of service definition and service wsdl are not in sync. You may need to check with service author if wsdl is handcrafted or auto generated.

Comment: Is this something I can check myself without the service guy (who has gone home)? The wsdl that I can see looks ok. See above.